# ClassCastException when adding LayoutParams

Tags: android

Which class do I have to use, when setting the `LayoutParams` of my `LinearLayout`? The following two are not working:

1. `linLayout.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(50,50));`
2. `linLayout.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50,50));`

if I get the params first, change them and set them back it's working. So I suppose the Params I get returned inherit from ViewGroup.LayoutParams...

Any idea? THX

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the LayoutParams of the parent. So in case your LinearLayout is a child of RelativeLayout then you use 
`linLayout.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(50,50));`

Comment: crazy, thats cool :) why use these params and not the LinearLayout params?

Comment: I don't know an exact answer, but LayoutParams are used by views to tell their parents how they want to be laid out. And this is parent specific (depends on the parent Layout type). So also when you are you are casting linlayout.getLayoutParams, cast it to (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) in this case.

Comment: That is one of the stupidess designs I've ever seen. Setting it on the parent? Seriously, WTF?

Comment: @AndroidDev :/ u need to understand it a little more